# Type-safe data fetching hooks with SWR and the fetch api?

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch, swr

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to abstract the data fetching hooks I've created, with Typescripts generics, for my React app. Unfortunately my understanding of Typescript isn't as good as I'd hope so I'm in a pickle.

The hooks I'm using are based on the [example](https://swr.vercel.app/getting-started#make-it-reusable) given by SWR, the data fetching library I'm using. They have an [example](https://github.com/vercel/swr/blob/master/examples/axios-typescript/libs/useRequest.ts) of what I'd like to build, in their repository but it's using Axios, while I'm using fetch (or isomorphic-unfetch to be exact).

To be explicit, I have `useUsers` hook to fetch all the users from my users endpoint, like so:

```
import useSWR from 'swr';
import fetcher from '../fetcher';
import { User } from '@prisma/client';

type UserHookData = {
    appUser?: User;
    isLoading: boolean;
    isError: any;
};
type UserPayload = {
    user?: User;
};

function useUsers(): UserHookData {
    const { data, error } = useSWR<UserPayload>('/api/users/', fetcher);
    const userData = data?.user;
    return {
        appUser: userData,
        isLoading: !error && !data,
        isError: error,
    };
}

export default useUsers;
```

The fetcher function used is copied directly from one of their typescript [examples](https://github.com/vercel/swr/blob/master/examples/basic-typescript/libs/fetch.ts) and I'm using Prisma as my ORM so I can access the types through it. The `User` type has fields like email and name.

I've got another, almost identical hook to fetch a single project from my project end point:

```
import useSWR from 'swr';
import fetcher from '../fetcher';
import { Project } from '@prisma/client';

type ProjectHookData = {
    project: Project;
    isLoading: boolean;
    isError: any;
};

type ProjectPayload = {
    project?: Project;
};

function useProject(id: number): ProjectHookData {
    const { data, error } = useSWR<ProjectPayload>(`/api/project/${id}`, fetcher);
    const project = data?.project;
    return {
        project,
        isLoading: !error && !data,
        isError: error,
    };
}

export default useProject;
```

What I'd like to do is have one hook (let's call it useRequest like in the SWR example) that I can fetch most of the data I need. With regular Javascript, I'd probably write it like this:

```
function useRequest(url, key){
    const { data: payload, error } = UseSWR(url, fetcher);
    const data = payload[key]
    return {
         data,
         isLoading: !error && !data,
         isError: error
   };
}
```

But how would I do this in Typescript, when I want to use this for multiple different data types? I thought about maybe using generics for this, but I'm unsure if it's the correct way to solve this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following hook, using generics, seems to work:

```
import useSWR from 'swr';
import fetcher from './fetcher';

interface DataPaylaod<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

interface DataResponse<T> {
    data: T;
    isLoading: boolean;
    isError: any;
}

function useRequest<T>(url: string, key: string): DataResponse<T> {
    const { data: payload, error } = useSWR<DataPaylaod<T>>(url, fetcher);
    const data = payload ? payload[key] : undefined;
    return {
        data,
        isLoading: !data && !error,
        isError: error,
    };
}

export default useRequest;
```

At least it passes `tsc` and returns the data in the form I'm expecting. If anyone has a more elegant solution, I'd love to see it as well.